# what happens after a process calls ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...)?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, gdb

After a process calls ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, ...), where the tracee stoped?

Is the tracee stoped in `exec()` system call? (seems not)

Is the tracee stoped in dynamic linker text?

...

If I compile a executable without any dynamic link libraries and glibc c-runtime, and specify the entry-point,
the tracee would stop at the entry-point.

But when I compile a executable with glibc(`gcc hello-world.c`), it would stoped at `/lib/ld-2.20.so offset + 0xfb0`. (cat /proc/[pid]/maps)

Hope more details about this.

`man ptrace` seems no help.

Answer (score 0):

The tracee is usually stopped when a call to `execve()` is done which will cause it to be sent a SIGTRAP.
Some uses `raise()` to ensure a signal is sent, like this :

```
ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME);
kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
return execvp(args[0], args);
```

Comment: thx. so, when the tracee is stopped, the CPU EIP register points to which instruction?

Comment: Well, i would say it contains the `execve()` system call number, but i'm not sure at all, so you can check it yourself with gdb, there is a command (`info reg`) that will show you the values of your process registers !

Comment: sorry for my ambiguous statements. When the tracee is stopped, the CPU EIP register points to a instruction. What's this instruction? It belongs to glibc, dynamic linker, or others?

Comment: It's probably a system call wrapper from glibc C that was called last (execve() in this case)

Comment: the `execve()` never returns(if there is no error), so there is no chance to stopped at the wrapper... :(

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP);
> return execvp(args[0], args);
> ```
>
> thx. so, when the tracee is stopped, the CPU EIP register points to which instruction?

The specification of the [`kill(pid_t pid, int sig)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) function answers this.

> If the value of *pid* causes *sig* to be generated for the sending
>   process, and if *sig* is not blocked for the calling thread and if no
>   other thread has *sig* unblocked or is waiting in a *sigwait()* function
>   for *sig*, either *sig* or at least one pending unblocked signal shall be
>   delivered to the sending thread before *kill()* returns.

So, due to the above `kill(getpid(), SIGSTOP)` the process is stopped before the library function *kill()* returns, typically at the instruction just after the system call.